Automating the checking of formatting issues
I'm taking a large number of documents that are in one format and using some tools to convert them into a different format. My concern is that some of the formatting could have been compromised during this conversion (e.g. spacing between titles, complex lists or tables getting corrupted, etc.).
So for each of my converted documents I have one simple question: "Is the formatting of this document print-ready and would pass muster with eagle-eyed editors?".
I'm not really qualified to do this and the number of documents is large, so brilliant idea: I'll use NotebookLM.
So I loaded up my files and asked NotebookLM to find all of the places where the formatting did not look professional and the results were...... ehhh.
So my question is: Is there a better way to get what I want?

What formats were you converting between? It's simple enough (with code) to know if a bullet point character from Doc A was converted to  in Doc B, but only a limited number of issues can be reliably identified with only the final product (e.g. TitleWithSpacesRemoved.)

What does that have to do with writing? Quality control of file conversion seems like a programming question.

@Laurel I'm essentially going between HTML and PDF, and OMG!!! it is NOT a simple coding exercise to check the output given all of the craziness of CSS. And besides, that's not even the point which is "Is this PDF ready to go to a publisher?" As for is this a "writing" question - not exactly but who better to know about tools to check on the formatting of a document?

Sander, you need a human to check a document for formatting issues. As you certainly know, there is no software that has been tested against all possible use cases, so you can never be sure if an automated check recognizes all issues in your sample. You can go through the origin documents and try and understand what issues your autmation might face and then test it against these and hope you didn't miss other potential problems. Or you can look at each output and verify and correct it manually. I'm sure there are libraries that convert from PDF to HTML, but that is a programming question.
